# MATLAB: Transforming a combination of strings as one

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, element

Let's say I have

```
a = [ 'i=' num2str(0)]

a = 
   i=0
```

and

```
A = zeros(2);
B = num2str(A)

B = 
   0 0
   0 0
```

This `i=0` is considered a `1x3` matrix: `[ i, =, 0]`. Now how do I transform this into one element so that I can replace `B(1,1)` with `i=0`? I want to get

```
B = 

 i=0    0
   0    0
```

(This is the reason why I converted `A` into string.)

I kept getting this error:

```
Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton
```

subscripts

which I suspect was due to `a`'s dimension.

I've tried `strcat(a)`, and some other methods.

### Edit:

The motivation behind it is from my attempt to put in labels into a matrix while executing a loop.

This is the last portion of my code:

```
n5 = length(X(1, :));
n6 = length(X(:, 1)) + 1;

Y = zeros(n6, n5);
Y(2:n6, :) = X;
Z = num2str(Y, 4);
for i = 0:K
a = ['i=' num2str(i)];
Z(1,i+1) = a;
end

X = Z

end
```

I want the output to show:

```
   i=0      i=1    ...     i=K

1.0022   1.0000    ...  1.0000
2.0081   2.0000    ...  2.0000
4.0011   4.0000    ...  4.0000
3.9811   4.0000    ...  4.0000
```

I'm aware we can format the output in another way, but not in loops. I want to use loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take 2:
I find it difficult to find a way to store in a **matrix** both strings (`i=0`...) as well as numbers. I would recommend the use of cell array

```
sz = size( X );
Z(2,:) = mat2cell( X, sz(1), ones(1,sz(2)) ); % convert each column of X into cell
Z(1,:) = arrayfun( @(x) sprintf('i=%d',x), 0:(sz(2)-1), 'uni', false );
```

The resulting cell array `Z` is of size `2x(n5)` and would look like:

   `'i=0'           'i=1'           'i=2'           'i=3'           'i=4'

    [5x1 double]    [5x1 double]    [5x1 double]    [5x1 double]    [5x1 double]`

Where `Z{2,ii}` is the `ii`-th column of matrix `X`.